# Rails how to handle parsed json

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating a rake task that parses a JSON object array and needs to run through each element of the json array. Here is a sample of the JSON object I am trying to iterate through

**response.body**

```
{"result":"[{\"accounts\":\"1668\",\"accu\":\"568\",\"activePayingRate\":\"1.97757\"},
{\"accounts\":\"1554\",\"accu\":\"497\",\"activePayingRate\":\"2.18398\"},
{\"accounts\":\"2314\",\"accu\":\"491\",\"activePayingRate\":\"2.43795\"},
{\"accounts\":\"2825\",\"accu\":\"511\",\"activePayingRate\":\"2.33333\"}]","errorMsg":"success"}
```

I have tried this

```
    result = JSON.parse(response.body)["result"]
    result.each do |r|
        puts r["accu"]
    end
```

But then I got this error

```
undefined method `each' for #<String:0x007fc81dc6fb78>
```

So then I tried this

```
    result = JSON.parse(response.body)
    result.each do |r|
        puts r["accu"]
    end
```

But then I got this error

```
can't convert String into Integer
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution, but I dont like it at all. This is a ridiculous solution but it works. I parse the response twice in this solution

```
    result = JSON.parse(response.body)["result"]
    result = JSON.parse(result)
    result.each do |r|
        puts r["accu"]
    end
```

Comment: Yes i figured that. the makers of this API keep screwing up the JSON. But I was still hoping for a better fix than the one I provided